# VSCode on Ubuntu, clean reinstall

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

used Sublime Keymappings for years in vscode, but now I want to switch back to default mappings. 
So I tried to make a clean reinstall of vscode,following the suggestions on stackoverflow to do so - but I failed.

So far I tried

```
$ sudo apt remove code && sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove vscode (or visual-sudio-code or code)
$ sudo dpkg --remove vscode //or code etc
$ sudo dpkg --purge vscode
```

I also deleted

```
~/.vscode and 
~/.config/Code
```

after a "fresh" install I end up with all extensions and settings I manually installed before. Quite anoying ;)

Do I miss something?

I'd appreciate any suggestions helping me out here, thx

Comment: According to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_where-are-extensions-installed), extensions are saved in `~/.vscode/extensions`... Are you using anything to sync settings/extensions?

Comment: Sometimes I use settings sync to update my packages on different machines, but I didn't use it when trying to do the clean reinstall

Comment: Anyway I could at least I change back to VSCodes Keyboard shortcuts by copying them from another machine

Answer (score 3):

The steps you took are correct, some even unnecessary.

Just run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge code

rm -r ~/.vscode/

rm -r ~/.config/Code/
```

This will also reset the configurations and you can perform a clean installation.

Instead, if VSCode has been installed with snap, the first line becomes:

```
sudo snap remove code
```

Comment: Be _very_ careful with `sudo`, especially when pairing it with destructive commands like `rm -r`. Only use `sudo` when you actually need to. Throwing it in front of commands out of habit is a terrible idea, and unless OP did something weird it should not be required in the `rm -r` steps here.

Comment: The two commands `rm -r` are needed, because VSCode store there information about extensions and/or global config.
The two commands won't work without `sudo` because some file in those folders request permissions.
It's also true it's not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove com.visualstudio.code
```